# Spring Data Cassandra Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra, datastax-astra

I am trying to connect my AstraDatabase (Cassandra) with my spring boot application. I had done all the configuration needed when I used to run it. It shows me exception:**Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0**.
It shows me the **"config.json"** file is missing although it is present in my secure-bundle.zip in resources as an absolute location.

```
2022-09-10 09:46:08.073  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] i.b.b.BetterreadsDataLoaderApplication   : Starting BetterreadsDataLoaderApplication using Java 18.0.2 on 192.168.10.2 with PID 2807 (/Volumes/A-CONTAINER/Spring Workspace/betterreads-data-loader/target/classes started by ahmadmujtaba in /Volumes/A-CONTAINER/Spring Workspace/betterreads-data-loader)
2022-09-10 09:46:08.075  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] i.b.b.BetterreadsDataLoaderApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-09-10 09:46:08.206  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-09-10 09:46:09.171  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-10 09:46:09.191  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
2022-09-10 09:46:09.203  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-10 09:46:09.206  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 2 ms. Found 0 Cassandra repository interfaces.
2022-09-10 09:46:09.865  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] c.d.o.d.api.core.session.SessionBuilder  : Both a secure connect bundle and contact points were provided. These are mutually exclusive. The contact points from the secure bundle will have priority.
2022-09-10 09:46:10.058  WARN 2807 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json
2022-09-10 09:46:10.075  INFO 2807 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-09-10 09:46:10.121 ERROR 2807 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at io.betterreads.betterreadsdataloader.BetterreadsDataLoaderApplication.main(BetterreadsDataLoaderApplication.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.config.cloud.CloudConfigFactory.createCloudConfig(CloudConfigFactory.java:114) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildDefaultSessionAsync(SessionBuilder.java:876) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.buildAsync(SessionBuilder.java:817) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.SessionBuilder.build(SessionBuilder.java:835) ~[java-driver-core-4.14.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraSession(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:88) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 36 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

DataStaxProperties class:

```
package io.betterreads.betterreadsdataloader.connection;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.io.File;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datastax.astra")
public class DataStaxProperties {
    private File secureConnectBundle;

    public File getSecureConnectBundle() {
        return secureConnectBundle;
    }

    public void setSecureConnectBundle(File secureConnectBundle) {
        this.secureConnectBundle = secureConnectBundle;
    }
}
```

Main class with @Bean:

```
package io.betterreads.betterreadsdataloader;

import io.betterreads.betterreadsdataloader.connection.DataStaxProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import java.nio.file.Path;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataStaxProperties.class)
public class BetterreadsDataLoaderApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BetterreadsDataLoaderApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer sessionBuilderCustomizer(DataStaxProperties astraProperties){
        Path bundle=astraProperties.getSecureConnectBundle().toPath();
        return builder-> builder.withCloudSecureConnectBundle(bundle);
    }
}
```

Application.yml file:

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: main
      username:   HLXgDtUfdYFcCHZyYUvBsxqT
      password: -uJ2OmJq2J4dHJzWO95C3357DIeO1zj2rcEOX7BHHBGOIlbhpaFdO2ZOzuZDTQydo2aS1J6htIyBsD4v5L9UrSsI7fb9gFZlY3OAQAl,AO5jzgMIyj6kpLYCSWL6Dz30
      schema-action: create-if-not-exists
      request:
        timeout: 10s
      connection:
        connect-timeout: 10s
        init-query-timeout: 10s

datastax.astra:
  secure-connect-bundle: secure-connect.zip


astra:
  db:
    id: 01592499-a522-46ad-a0d8-7695a4d3e3a0
    region: us-east1
    keyspace: main
    application:
      token: AstraCS:HLXgDtUfdYFcCHZyYUvBsxqT:cdd600be8fa60f5656b770ff587f0b139fe575c45cd657be5dd5b47b09bd131c
```

Answer (score 0):

did you created keyspace in cassandra , If your keypsace =main is not created you will get this error.

Please find working example

- https://github.com/vaquarkhan/spring-boot-data-cassandra-microservice

Comment: Yes! I have created the keyspace 'main' you can see in .yml file

Comment: Invalid bundle: missing file config.json

Answer (score 0):

It troubled me as well, but it worked fine when I gave it a reference to the ZIP file itself instead of the unzipped folder.